# Usar variable data source flujo de datos SSIS

Tags: sql-server, variables, ssis

En SSIS, tengo una variable que coge el valor de una query definida en un componente "Tarea Ejecutar SQL". El valor de la variable se asigna correctamente. Lo que quiero hacer luego es dentro de un "Flujo de datos", usando un "origen de ADO", donde se define la query usar en el `where` la variable utilizada anteriormente.

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo? He buscado por todos sitios y no encuentro nada de esto.

He probado con algo como

```
SELECT col1,col2... 
  FROM tabla 
 WHERE col1 = @nombreVar.
```

Answer (score 1):

En la fuente de datos (`Source`), elige data access mode `SQL Command` y en el where especificas que vas a usar un parametro usando un signo de interrogación **?**

```
Select col1, col2, col3
from tabla
where col1 =?
```

Luego haces click en el botón `Parameters` y allí eliges la variable `(User::NombreDeVariable)` y dejas `input` como la dirección